# Standards for parking restriction spatial data

Tags: geospatial, city, standards, parking

I'm working with some local governments in Australia to publish parking restriction data. Are there any existing standards to conform to? The kind of data I'm talking about:

- spatial (one polygon per zone that has a shared set of restrictions)
- several restrictions at different times (eg, 2 hours between 9:00 and 17:00, unlimited after)
- may also have special restrictions: loading zones, clearways, disabled access...

An example of such (non-standardised) data: http://data.gov.au/dataset/ballarat-car-parking-areas

Comment: I would think that because each state has its own road rules, I doubt you'll find a standard across Australia.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think those two things are very connected. The difference in road rules is pretty minor, and I can't think of any examples that would affect parking. If you mean "because each state has its own roads authority", that's also not totally pertinent, because most of this data is held by local governments, not roads authorities.